# How to handle SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; Incorrect string value?

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

I'm aware this error means a mysql column doesn't accept the value, but this is strange, since the value fits in a Java UTF-8 encoded string, and the mysql column is utf8_general_ci. Also, all utf8 characters have worked properly so far, apart from these.

The use-case is: I am importing tweets. The tweet in question is: https://twitter.com/bakervin/status/210054214951518212 - you can see the two "strange" characters (and two strange whitespaces between them). The question is - how to handle this:

- trim these characters (how - which are they, how does the Java UTF-8 differ from MySQL one)
- make the column capable of accepting this value (how - is there anything more utf-y than utf8_general_ci)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These appear to be [unicode surrogate characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates). Since they are not actual characters, and it seems MySQL doesn't support them, it is safe to trim them:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char ch = text.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isHighSurrogate(ch) && !Character.isLowSurrogate(ch)) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by changing the collation of the DB from utf_8 to utf_16.